# Tool to convert OGG files to WMA?

Tags: software-recommendation, tools, wma, ogg-vorbis

I have a bunch of OGG files that I would like to convert to WMA (v9) format.

Is there a native Ubuntu tool I can use for this? (Since WMA is a proprietary format, I'm guessing that there won't be a tool that does this in the repos.)

Comment: but why that's like converting wine in to water

Comment: @Allan: We had better get a good answer... this is already climbing up in the search results for 'ubuntu convert ogg wma' :)

Comment: @allan: I'd say gold into mud (to not say sh*t).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a way to convert OGG files to WMA (v8) files using [VLC](http://videolan.org):

1. Launch VLC and go to File->Convert / Save

   [image]
2. Add the files you want to convert by clicking 'Add...' and then click 'Convert / Save'

   [image]
3. Select the destination file, remembering to append the `.wma` extension

   [image]
4. Click the button to create a new profile (this only needs to be done once)

   [image]
5. Give the new profile a name, and select 'ASF / WMV' for encapsulation

   [image]
6. Click the 'Audio' tab and change the settings to match this image (or make any changes if you want a different bitrate or something):

   [image]
7. Click 'Save' and select your new format

   [image]
8. Now simply click 'Start' and your files will be transcoded

Answer (score 7):

`ffmpeg -i file.ogg -ac 2 -ab 128k file.wma`

Answer (score 4):

I really don't know enough about encapsulation and audio formats, and I have no idea why you'd want to take something good and make it worse, BUT...

VLC appears to have the functionality you required.

[image: VLC convert dialogue]

Not a full answer, but hopefully something to start you off.

Comment: Lol... I just finished a long tutorial answer with screenshots saying the exact same thing :P